# How to ssh-add elliptic curve key?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent, ssh-keygen, elliptic-curve-crypto

I'm trying to use a newly generated elliptic curve key with git version control for GitLab.

- I am using a Xubuntu 16.04.
- My OpenSSH version is: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Usually I would do:

```
ssh-add -D  # to be sure no other identities are used than the one I add
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-rsa-key
git add ...
git commit ...
git push ...
```

Then the key ring thing would again ask for the password of the key to store it for the session and I could push and pull without needing to add any key again or entering the password again.

However with elliptic curve keys it does not seem to work. First of all, I cannot `ssh-add` the key:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:  # here I enter my password
Could not add identity "/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519": communication with agent failed
```

However, when I did not remove all identities and did not use `ssh-add <key>` and cancelled entering a password for the key ring for other (rsa) keys, I was asked to enter the password for the elliptic curve key on command line and when I entered it there, I could push to or pull from my repository. The problem then is, that I have to enter my password on every interaction with gitlab and my repository. So I tried configuring my `~/ssh/config` to not prompt for password all the time:

```
Host gitlab.com
  User "user"
  PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
  IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

But that does not work either, it keeps nagging me about the password on every pull or push.

How can I add the keys like I do with RSA keys, so that I do not have to enter the password all the time?